# Is it possible to get extra info from "unfortunately app has stopped working" error?

Tags: android, logging, error-handling

In my app when some services of it are running it suddenly displays that message on some occasions, but most of the time they work properly, when I've tested them I haven't had any problem.

I'd like to know if its possible to associate the event that causes that message to appear, with giving some extra information or at the very least writing a log that at least shows which class and what line of code causes the error.

From there I could investigate with greater ease what makes that message to appear, as right now I've no clue.

Comment: you can see, check your logs

Comment: @Ozan. Problem is that I think that "unfortunately app has stopped working" is an Error, not an Exception, so it cannot be caught, buy maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know if its possible to associate the event that causes that message to appear, with giving some extra information or at the very least writing a log that at least shows which class and what line of code causes the error.

Every time that dialog appears, a Java stack trace is written to LogCat automatically. [You can use Android Studio or other development tools to examine LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check.